# Run a particular ssh command in background for 24/7 on VPS server

Tags: linux, ssh, fedora, netcat

I have a VPS server with Bluehost(fedora OS), I wanted to capture data from remote application via `TCP` and to write the same onto a file for further processing. So I am using `netcat` for that.

```
 nc -l -k -v IP_ADDRESS_HERE 5331 > /home/user/public_html/tcp/data.xml
```

by using above command in `ssh`, the `Netcat` listens to a particular port and writes a captured data on to a file called `data.xml`.

**The Problem:** I want this command to run continuously even after closing ssh terminal, and even after server is restarted. I used to `screen` and `nohup`. These options not going to be the solution as it won't run if the server is restarted.

How do i do that? using some scripts?, I am bit new to this field, please help me.

Thanks in advance :)

**Update:** Even in ssh terminal, above command works perfect but automatically ends with `^C` after some time. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the job needs to resume after system reboot, it's a system service. So you have several options:

- Write an init script and add it to your default run level.
- If your distro uses `systemd` write a configuration file to start your command as a service.
- You can use another service manager like `supervisord` to automatically run your command.
- Custom quick and dirty solution. When I need something to run automatically in a `screen`, I often use a `cron` entry like this :

  @reboot screen -S my_service -d -m bash -c 'my_command' > /dev/null

At reboot, it will start your command in a screen and detach.

Comment: Thanks, Can you help me to write a init script or systemd configuration file to run this single command? since I am using fedora, i think fedora supports both the above methods.
P.S : I am really new to Linux.

Comment: The man pages are great (systemd, systemd.unit, & bootup).
Arch linux has excellent documentation that may help you:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Writing_custom_.service_files

Comment: Now that you have the info what prevents you from writing the config yourself ?